# Unable to Load PAF( Portal Application Framework) setting

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

Paf.Config.GetConfigSection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["oauth:settings"]) is throwing exception
error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Wrapped_IConfigProvider_1d5f3f8c86af4710ad1878f29267b31c' does not exist in the namespace 'DynamicModule.ns' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Resulting to 
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: rsa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was because the certificate that needs to run PAF was not installed properly.